# Concatenate columns per row in pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

In R its easy:

```
df = data.frame(a = letters[1:5], b = letters[6:10], c = letters[11:15],stringsAsFactors = F)
df$tot = apply(df,MARGIN = 1,function(x){paste(x,collapse = "")})
```

in Python Pandas i tried:

```
df.apply(lambda row: ''.join(str(row)), axis=1)
```

and it leads to a crazy result, also adding columns headers to strings.

I have to migrate from R to Python and I found its very counter-intuitive to do simple things such as this operation. Could anyone explain the logic why colnames got included?

Comment: how working `df.astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)` ?

Comment: Perhaps explain what are the input and expected output, so we don't have to learn R to answer this Python question ;-)

Comment: Also how working `df.astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

str(row) tranforms row into a string, ex:

```
str([1, 2, 3]) => '[1, 2, 3]'
str(['a','b']) => '["a", "b"]'
```

and ''.join(x) where x is a string returns the same string. So your lambda transforms a row in a string.

But it seems what you want is: to transform every element of row into a string before joining them:

```
lambda row: ''.join(str(x) for x in row)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Somehow I thought python will vectorize `str()` in the same manner as R does.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
df.apply(lambda row: ''.join(str(row)), axis=1)
```

row is a pandas Series and str(row) is the string representation of this Series (which you can see when you do print(row)).

If I correctly understand what you want to do, you want to get the list of the values inside the series and concatenate them. Which could be written as:

```
df.apply(lambda row: "".join(row.values), axis=1)
```